# Laravel 5.4: post route without a form or to hide the url

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

I have the following **route** in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('search/{model}/{lang}/{id}', ['as'=>'tag','uses'=>'SearchController@tag']);
```

In the **view** I have a foreach with the tags:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('tag', ['model'=>'new', 'lang'=>$lang, $tag->id]) }}">
        {{$tag_lang->name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

And what I want is that in the browser only appears the "search" url without the parameters model, lang and id (**domain.com/search** instead of **domain.com/search/model/lang/id**), but I don´t want to use a form. Is there any way to use a post route without a form or to hide the url? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: NO. A link can mimic a GET. Never a POST.

Comment: What you can do is make a form look like a link.

Comment: use post and ajax button, dont need form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a post look like an anchor:

```
<style type="text/css">
    form.link_mimic {display:inline}
    form.link_mimic input {display:inline;padding:0;border-width:0;margin:0;background:none;color:blue}
    form.link_mimic input:hover {text-decoration:underline}
</style>

    Click <form class="link_mimic" method="post" action="my_url">
      <input type="hidden" name="lang" value=" {{$tag->id}}">
      <input type="submit" value="{{$tag_lang->name}}">
    </form> to change the language.
```

Give it a go, maybe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: The problem with use a FORM it´s that maybe I have 20 tags in a page, then, Do I have to do 20 forms or 20 submits? Thats why I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: 20 forms? Well, it's not that hard. any small image will make your page longer to take thatn 20 tiny forms, and I guess those 20 forms will be programmatically written using a loop, so...

Comment: Well, you have convinced me, I will use forms ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a POST route instead as then the parameters will not be visible as querystrings. An example route would be as follows:

```
Route::post('search', ['as'=>'tag','uses'=>'SearchController@tag']);
```

You would however need to convert your href into a form.

If you do need to use GET then look at converting query strings using hashing or encryption to obfuscate them from the user and then decode the result in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don´t want to use a form and I don´t need to obfuscate the paramaters, it´s only a question of seo. Thanks anyway.